# Plot two data sets on the same axes but offset along the x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure

Probably my explanation is not good, I need following kind of graphs. Matlab, sigmaplot solution will be welcomed. Graphpad Prism may also be an option.

[image]

The x-axis is splitted, actually 2 data sets (same x-axis but different y-axis). it is error plot (mean I also need error bars)

Comment: You should probably search the Mathworks website before you resort to posting a question here. The first result for 'matlab error bar' shows there is an [errorbar function](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html), and searching for 'Matlab plot with 2 y axes' leads to the [yyaxis](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html#bunqz2o-1_1) function. Combining these will give you what you were looking for.

Comment: Sir, thanks for the comment. If you can see at the question, i'm not sure how to put the question (i tried to use best possible words). I need the graph as shown in the figure, y.yaxis does not show such thing. please suggest a correction that make the question more understandable. Thanks

Comment: Could you post a code of you tried already?

Comment: As @Marouen says, please show the code you have tried and the resulting plot, and explain what is wrong with what you have so far. As a hint though, if you add 60 to all the x-values in the second dataset then it should appear in the right place... then all you need to do is get the x-axis labels to appear the way you want.

Comment: Also I don't think that the presentation of the x-axis scale on the plots in your example is ideal - there should be a break in the line to show that the scale is not continuous, and it's a bit unconventional to place the axis ticks in between the scale values like that - if this is done to imply that the x-values are approximate or binned rather than precisely 40, 50, 60 etc then I would remove the ticks altogether. Unless you have a requirement to reproduce this plot exactly then I would take a moment to think about how it could be improved on.

Comment: @nekomatic..... Sir the above graphs were not developed by me, i want to plot those types of graphs. There is actually nothing wrong with anything. I recently concluded that these are actually two different graphs, y-axis of one is removed and then "merged" with other graph.These are actually scientific graphs and used in research articles, hence should be precise.